# Newb question: "service" command unavailable on CentOS 5.5

Tags: bash, service, centos5, command

[Pages like this](http://www.how-to-linux.com/2009/03/how-to-open-port-80-on-iptables-on-centos/) say that you can

```
service iptables restart
```

...but I get a `command not found` error.  I tried `yum install service` but there's no such package.

How do I restart services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `/sbin/service iptables` restart ?

Comment: `sudo` in front of that worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

["How To Become Root"](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BecomingRoot)

Comment: Good point.  I'd sort of assumed he had become root with "/bin/su" not "/bin/su -", so lacked the PATH.  If that's true, my answer is probably more immediately helpful, but yours is way better in the long run.

Comment: I had tried `sudo service iptables restart` and gotten the same message.  Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @Kev: Did you read the article?

Comment: Ah, I see it does answer the question, in "The reason is that regular system users and the root user have different PATH environment variables (you can view a users PATH with 'echo $PATH')."  However, the other answer got it working for me much quicker.  :)  (I still gave +1 to you...)